# Sell Windows Phone 7 Apps outside of App Hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, distribution, windows-phone

Is it possible to (legally) sell WP7 apps outside of Microsoft's App Hub? Are there license restrictions to this? Is it ideal to even approach app distribution in such a manner (i.e., are there other sites/services that are easily accessible by WP7 users to find new apps).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly speaking, I'm not aware of any restrictions in place to prevent exchange (commercial or otherwise) of xap files outside of the marketplace.

However, to deploy the xap files the would be users would have to have an active marketplace account. Even then, you're limited to 10 apps deployed not via the marketplace.

These points would make it impractical to reach a broader audience than developers outside of the marketplace.

There are no sites specialising in this. Perhaps as a result of it being not an ideal/worthwhile scenario.

Comment: Thanks Mick, your answer is more complete.

Answer (score 3):

No, the App Hub is the only place you can sell your WP7 apps.

Comment: Is that a restriction set by the phone OS, licensing or maybe a combination?

Comment: @jlafay this is a restriction imposed by the OS. It is enforced by Microsoft to prevent "rogue" apps accessing data/functionality they shouldn't. The phones have the ability to be remotely disabled by Microsoft should such an app somehow get through. In that you can't use a phone for very much without first associating a LiveID this should be quite effective.

Answer (score 1):

From a developer end I don't think I would want to distribute outside the marketplace.

Microsoft has taken steps to protect the developer’s intellectual property and the prevention of app leak prevention.

Windows Phone 7 App Protection white paper.  [link text](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/8/588D2A2D-9AE6-4383-B081-F6BDD4445761/Windows%20Phone%20Marketplace%20Anti-Piracy%20Model.docx)

Comment: Well... Some might want to take their own steps, not pay 30% and add more payment options (like charging company instead of people).