# Can you install you own apps on your windows 7 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sideloading

I'm trying to create my own small Windows 7 Phone app.  I have downloaded the tools and I'm writing code.  I'm wondering how I can install my app on my phone?  Do I have to register to become an app developer and then upload my code?  Is there a way to distribute my app outside of the marketplace?

I found this link: [Sell Windows Phone 7 Apps outside of App Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139063/sell-windows-phone-7-apps-outside-of-app-hub)

But I'm not referring to selling my app.  More like me testing it before I put it up on the marketplace.  Is there any references on how to install my app on my own phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to register as a developer, then you will be able to register your phone in the Zune software, allowing you to sideload the apps and debug them on the phone. IIRC you can have three devices registered to a single account.

There's no way of distributing apps outside the marketplace, other than to other developers (who would be able to deploy your XAP file on their phones in the same way as if it were their own app).

Given that you're thinking of putting it on the marketplace, you'll need to register anyway - so do it now and take advantage of the ability to test it on your device right away :)

Comment: @Jon - To do that does that cost $99 per year?

Comment: @Jeff V: Yes, but you'd need to do that anyway.

Comment: @Jon - Why do it now?  Is the fee going to go up soon?

Comment: @Jeff V: No, but it means you'll be able to test your app. Do you think you're really likely to change how many years you end up paying for by delaying?

Comment: @Jon - No I'm just trying to wrap my head around this whole thing.  Thanks for your knowledge.  I appreciate it.  I'll finish up my app and then I'll have to probably either wait for after Christmas or make that my Christmas gift to myself.  :)

Comment: @Jon - Does the 99 dollars come with cloud application account or something so that I can do Push Notification?

Comment: @JeffV if you're a good developer... heck I'll pay your fees for a bit of programming work in exchange... ;)

Comment: @samyi $99 is about 1 hours worth of work ;) - If you want to contact me goto my website @ webdad3.com

Comment: $99 dollars might not sound like a lot for someone in U.S. but the truth is when you see U.S.$99 in another currency, it could be a lot, like in my country, the minimum wage is less than U.S.$200 a month. They might be asking for a week's work of salary just so you can install your own app in your own phone (that might not be even worth the money itself)

Comment: @PedroC88 that's the point. It's quite surprising, given that, after all, Microsoft is vitally interested in Windows Phone getting traction. Whatever happened to "developers, developers, developers"? I'm a C# dev myself, but I'm learning Java on Android now instead of Windows Phone, as I can't see any encouragement from MS, and they only have 1-2% of the mobile OS market anyway. And it's not likely to pick up soon if things stay the way they are

Answer (score 10):

The [Windows Phone Anti-Piracy model](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/8/588D2A2D-9AE6-4383-B081-F6BDD4445761/Windows%20Phone%20Marketplace%20Anti-Piracy%20Model.docx) will only allows the phone to run signed apps unless it is unlocked. In order to unlock your phone you have to sign up for a developer account ([$99 per year](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/faq), free for students using [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/Products/Product.aspx?ProductId=28)) and even then you can only unlock a limited number of phones. Each application requests a license from the AppHub when installed to limit piracy:

> During installation, a license that validates execution rights is acquired for the application. The license is issued for the specific device and the specific Windows Live ID account associated with the Marketplace account through which the application was acquired. The license is stored on the device and contains information identifying the actual code delivered as part of the download. When an application is invoked, the loader obtains the license and verifies (a) that the application code matches the application code indicated on the license and (b) that the license specifically allows for running the specific application on the specific device. If the match is successful, then the application is loaded and run on the phone; if no license is matched to the application code, the application invocation fails and the application will not run.

**UPDATE 12/1/2010:** There is now a 'Jailbreak' called [ChevronWP7](http://www.chevronwp7.com/) that will allow you to unlock your phone and side-load unpublished applications without purchasing a developer account. It uses the [same API](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20101127/my-thoughts-on-my-thoughts-on-chevronwp7/) as the Visual Studio unlock tool, but can support loading more than the limited number of apps that you can side load using Visual Studio. It also allows you to load [custom ringtones](http://www.chevronwp7.com/post/2054291102/chevronwp7-custom-ringtone-manager), however due to the piracy protections listed above it will not let you install applications from the marketplace without first purchasing a license for them.

Comment: Sadly, as of January 22nd, ChevronWP7 doesn't appear to work any more. See here: http://www.chevronwp7.com/post/2885085987/a-first-step-in-the-right-direction

Comment: ChevronWP7 is now officially sanctioned by Microsoft. See http://labs.chevronwp7.com/

Answer (score 4):

From a process flow, side loading to you device requires a couple steps.

1. Registered as a developer at create.msdn.com
2. Downloaded the most recent tools at create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started
3. On your program list under your "Windows Phone Developer Tools" folder there is an application called 'Windows Phone Developer Registration'

That application will guide you though registering your device and then debugging / execution of your application through Visual Studio / Phone Express Edition

Developer registeration for device deployment is a common amoung other platforms as well.  The registeration fee is a great deal when you consider the platform distribution, as well as cross developement for Xbox 360 xna.  Check out [link text](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/membership) for full membership details.

Comment: Thank you for this info... Question though... Submit up to five free apps to Windows Phone Marketplace, additional submissions are $19.99 USD   Why would anyone pay to submit free apps?

Comment: @JeffV: I have attended various Windows Phone 7 launch events / meetings where that very question has been brought up. I have not see an official 'answer' from Microsoft but through discuss the general consensus has been that by putting a limit it reduces frivolous apps from flooding the marketplace.  From a developer end I aggree, if I reached my 5 free limit and had another great app then I would have no problem paying for that.  Hosting / displaying a free app in the marketplace consume resources just like a paid app and those resources cost money.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the windowsbreak today and it worked on my Samsung Focus.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/jailbreak-unlock-windows-phone-7/

It involves hitting a website, then entering some special codes on your phones dialer, then reboot and done. I was immediately able to install my own wp7 hello world app.

Comment: Is that a phone version, OS Version, unlock page version? what is that version number?

Comment: The `windowbreak project` won't unlock your phone if you update Windows to v. 7.10.8773.98.

Comment: does it stop working if was previously broken? or is that if you try to get it broken after updating first?

Comment: I didn't get the question, but I had my Samsung Focus Flash unlocked with windowbreak to sideload apps, after I update the OS that version and redoing the process, it doesn't unlock it anymore even though all steps complete normally, but when you try to sideload an app it says the phone is locked.