# Deploy a C program compiled in VS2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I have a compiled an older C++ program that runs fine in debug mode in VS2010 converted to VC++ 6 but I have no idea how to package or deploy the application.
VS2010 may not have anything to do with deploying the program at all but I thought I should mention it.
The "release" folder not only contains the executable but some "obj", "tlog", "vc100.pdb", "exe.intermediate.manifest" and "lastbuildstate".
This application is being installed on Windows Mobile OS (hopefully). It isn't as simple as copying the executable to the device is it?
Do I need to create a cab file or msi and, if so, how?
I am absolutely new at this being spoiled in C# and MVC for far too long!

Comment: You will need deploy your .exe file and any dependencies that it may have. The *.obj, *.tlog and all the other files can be ignored. Though depending on how you built your manifest, you sometimes have to deploy that too. Otherwise I know nothing about deploying to a windows phone OS.

Comment: Actually it is to a Symbol PT8800 handheld scanner.  I have no idea how this compares to a phone.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does not have any of the Smart Device compilers (managed or native) required to even build for Windows Mobile (not Windows Phone).  You must use Visual Studio 2008 to build, deploy and/or debug.

**EDIT**

FWIW, Studio 2012 will have support for Smart Devices (Studio 2010 still won't get support) in Q1 of next year.  Backward-compatibility has yet to be announced, but it's always possible that you'll be able to develop for WinMo devices using the ARM compiler.  There's [a video here](http://visualstudiolaunchstaging.social27.com/vs2012vle/Theater?sid=1776) detailng some of the features.

Comment: +1, maybe you can mention to OP, that both version of VS can be installed side-by-side on same PC

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  I'm going to install VS2008 Express and go from there.  Thanks again!

Comment: The Express SKUs also don't have the right compilers.  You need Studio 2008 Professional (or better).

Comment: Yaaaaay! Best news I've heard all year! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a search on google yet? While I don't know anything about deploying to a windows phone, a quick google search found a few hits.

I searched for 'deploy windows phone app' and found a few things. Among which are:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg588378(v=vs.92).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff928362(v=vs.92).aspx

Last of all, it looks like this has been asked before on this website. For instance:

[Can you install you own apps on your windows 7 phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229029/can-you-install-you-own-apps-on-your-windows-7-phone)

Comment: Yes, I searched and not just google.  Gobs of stuff for phones these days but this is for a handheld scanner.