# How I can test my app on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I made one windows phone 7 app and its working on emulator but I need to test the sensor... so to test the sensor I want to install the app in my phone... how I can do that? I don't want to put it in the market, I just want it for me...

Comment: This post might useful

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229029/can-you-install-you-own-apps-on-your-windows-7-phone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229029/can-you-install-you-own-apps-on-your-windows-7-phone

Comment: I need to pay 99 dollars for app that I made for myself and only I will use? Stupidest thing I ever heard...

Comment: Thats how it works, it's the same as it is for iOS-developers. You can however try out the app sensors using the emulator, can't remember exactly how find those features but they are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to have a developer unlock device for you to install your own app. and there is also a limit to how many you could install on your device.

if you are a student, you can get the subscription for free at dreamspark