# How to deploy private apps to Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, deployment

I'm looking to buy a Windows Phone smartphone, and am looking into the possibility for 'deploying' private apps. I currently own an Android system, and it's a simple as building an APK file, and adding it to the filesystem of any phone I want to install it on.

I realize there have been some questions around this subject [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308468/deploy-private-app-to-windows-8-phone), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229029/can-you-install-you-own-apps-on-your-windows-7-phone), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008252/sideloading-apps-on-windows-8-pro). They seem to say you either need a developers account, or an enterprise edition. These questions are old, and possibly outdated. I've tried to find more information on the topic, but all I could find was related to enterprise, or beta testing.

I have no interests in getting a developer's account, because I don't intend to develop or sell larger applications on the marketplace. It's mostly for private use.

If there is no way to do this by default (without paying any fees), are that alternatives that don't involve losing warranty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register yourself in [Windows App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us?stay=) and you will get to unlock one phone for development and side load up to 2 apps.
Currently that is the only way to put custom apps in your Windows Phone for free and without losing warranty.

If you, however register for a developer accout (which as you know has costs) you will be able to side load up to 10 apps in 3 different devices.

Comment: 2 apps sadly doesn't seem like enough for me, I'm quite surprised that Microsoft tries so hard to promote their platform while this essential piece of freedom isn't that free. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I know you said you don't want a developer account, but it's worth pointing out that a windows phone dev account is only $19. That will allow you to unlock 3 phones with up to 10 sideloaded apps.

Comment: @robwirving The post did mention that, but I read it was $99 a year. I found that the costs for an individual account is now $19 but couldn't find whether these costs are recurring. Are those fees annual?

Comment: They are annual. Although I'm not sure if phones automatically 're-lock' after a year if you don't renew your subscription.